# How to extract a very specific sets of string parts from QR decoded string?

Tags: java, android, string, split

I needed to pick specific parts of a very big string (that's being decoded from a QR code) to set as text in TextView elements in Android.

```
//*these are the parts of the string whose corresponding values I need as a text for my TextViews.*

String uid, name, gname, gender, house, street, ps, po, dist, subdist, state, pin, address, dob;

//*this 'string' object holds the decoded qr string*

String string = "uid="001" name="Akbar Shah" gender="M" yob="1989" gname="Jahangir Shah" co="S/O: Jahangir Shah" house="45/5" street="Huzurey Ala Street" vtc="Alibagh" po="Bagnan" dist="Faridabad" subdist="Alamgarh" state="Andhra" pc="6754674" dob="15/04/89"";

//*this is where I am using substring() to get a specific part of the string value*

uid = string.substring(string.indexOf("uid=")+5, string.indexOf("name=")-2);
name = string.substring(string.indexOf("name=")+6, string.indexOf("gender=")-2);
gname = string.substring(string.indexOf("gname=")+7, string.indexOf("co=")-2);
gender = string.substring(string.indexOf("gender=")+8, string.indexOf("yob=")-2);

house = string.substring(string.indexOf("house=")+7, string.indexOf("street=")-2);
street = string.substring(string.indexOf("street=")+8, string.indexOf("vtc=")-2);
ps = string.substring(string.indexOf("vtc=")+5, string.indexOf("po=")-2);
po = string.substring(string.indexOf("po=")+4, string.indexOf("dist=")-2);
dist = string.substring(string.indexOf("dist=")+6, string.indexOf("subdist=")-2);
subdist = string.substring(string.indexOf("subdist=")+9, string.indexOf("state=")-2);
state = string.substring(string.indexOf("state=")+7, string.indexOf("pc=")-2);
pin = string.substring(string.indexOf("pc=")+4, string.indexOf("dob=")-2);
dob = string.substring(string.indexOf("dob=")+5, string.indexOf("/>")-1);

//*this is where I have concatenated the whole address parts into one*
address = house+", "+street+", \nPS - "+ps+", \nPO - "+po+", \nDistrict - "+dist+", \nSub-Division - "+subdist+", \nState - "+state+", \nPin Code - "+pin;

 TextView tv_uid, tv_name, tv_gName, tv_gender, tv_address, tv_dob;

//*this is where  I then setText those substrings for appropriate TextViews*

                    tv_uid.setText(uid);
                    tv_name.setText(name);
                    tv_gName.setText(gname);
                    tv_gender.setText(gender);
                    tv_address.setText(address);
                    tv_dob.setText(dob);
```

The way I have done this can only work if the decoded QR string format remains the same, i.e. if the string decoded now is this:

> String string = "uid="001" name="Akbar Shah" gender="M" yob="1989" gname="Jahangir Shah" co="S/O: Jahangir Shah" house="45/5" street="Huzurey Ala Street" vtc="Alibagh" po="Bagnan" dist="Faridabad" subdist="Alamgarh" state="Andhra" pc="6754674" dob="15/04/89"";

Then, my way of extracting won't work if the string looks something like this:

> String string = "uid="002" name="Amar Tripathi" gender="M" yob="1990" vtc="Alibagh" po="Bagnan" dist="Faridabad" state="Andhra" pc="6754674" dob="15/04/89"";

Or, like this:

> String string = "uid="003" name="Anthony Gonzalis" gender="M" yob="1985" gname="Jahangir Shah" house="45/5" street="Huzurey Ala Street" lm="Behind the Meat shop" loc="Galianwalabagh" vtc="Alibagh" dist="Faridabad" state="Andhra" pc="6754674" dob="15/04/89"";

As you may have already noticed, substring() cannot be used universally for all cases because the last two string values have some parts missing in them. So if I specify to extract a particular substring which is sandwiched between gname and co, except for the first case, in the last two cases it won't be able to find co and hence the execution of the code line return error.
Is there a better way to do it?

P.S. Can I just extract all the string parts from inside " "?

E.g. "001" is the part of the string from which I just want to get the 001 part which is inside the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created a DataAttributes class.

DataAttributes.java

```
public class DataAttributes {
    // declare xml attributes of QR code xml response
    public static final String
            DATA_TAG = "PrintLetterBarcodeData",
            UID_ATTR = "uid",
            NAME_ATTR = "name",
            GENDER_ATTR = "gender",
            GNAME_ATTR = "gname",
            HOUSE_ATTR = "house",
            STREET_ATTR = "street",
            LM_ATTR = "lm",
            LOC_ATTR = "loc",
            VTC_ATTR = "vtc",
            PO_ATTR = "po",
            DIST_ATTR = "dist",
            SUBDIST_ATTR = "subdist",
            STATE_ATTR = "state",
            PC_ATTR = "pc",
            DOB_ATTR = "dob";
}
```

After QR code is being scanned and stored in a string.

In your activity where you want to display the scanned data, in my case its QRActivity... so I made a method with single argument -> (String scanData) in QRActivity class in QRActivity.java

Inside which the following code is written

```
    Log.d("QR Code",scanData);
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

    try {
        // init the parserfactory
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        // get the parser
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(scanData));

        // parse the XML
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                Log.d("QR Code","Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && DataAttributes.DATA_TAG.equals(parser.getName())) {
                // extract data from tag
                //uid
                uid = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.UID_ATTR);
                //name
                name = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.NAME_ATTR);
                //gender
                gender = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.GENDER_ATTR);
                // guardian name
                gname = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.GNAME_ATTR);
                // house number
                house = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.HOUSE_ATTR);
                // Street name
                street = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.STREET_ATTR);
                // landmark
                lm = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.LM_ATTR);
                // locality
                loc = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.LOC_ATTR);
                // village town city
                vtc = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.VTC_ATTR);
                // Post Office
                po = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.PO_ATTR);
                // district
                dist = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.DIST_ATTR);
                // sub-division
                subdist = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.SUBDIST_ATTR);
                // state
                state = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.STATE_ATTR);
                // Post Code
                pc = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.PC_ATTR);
                // Date of Birth
                dob = parser.getAttributeValue(null,DataAttributes.DOB_ATTR);


            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                Log.d("QR Code","End tag "+parser.getName());

            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                Log.d("QR Code","Text "+parser.getText());

            }
            // update eventType
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        // display the data on screen
        String na = "N/A";

            if (uid == null){
                        tv_uid.setText(na);
            }else {
                        tv_uid.setText(uid);
            }

            if (name == null){
                        tv_name.setText(na);
            }else {
                        tv_name.setText(name);
            }

            if (gender == null){
                        tv_gender.setText(na);
            }else {
                        tv_gender.setText(gender);
            }

            if (gname == null){
                tv_gName.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_gName.setText(gname);
            }

            if (house == null){
                tv_house.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_house.setText(house);
            }

            if (street == null){
                tv_street.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_street.setText(street);
            }

            if (lm == null){
                tv_lm.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_lm.setText(lm);
            }

            if (loc == null){
                tv_loc.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_loc.setText(loc);
            }

            if (vtc == null){
                tv_vtc.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_vtc.setText(vtc);
            }

            if (po == null){
                tv_po.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_po.setText(po);
            }

            if (dist == null){
                tv_dist.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_dist.setText(dist);
            }

            if (subdist == null){
                tv_subdist.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_subdist.setText(subdist);
            }

            if (state == null){
                tv_state.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_state.setText(state);
            }

            if (pc == null){
                tv_pc.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_pc.setText(pc);
            }

            if (dob == null){
                tv_dob.setText(na);
            }else {
                tv_dob.setText(dob);
            }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code is a sample of how I used XMLPullParserFactory to fragment a string into appropriate pieces and then show them separately.

Now you use the method appropriate for your purpose in the Activity. I just showed my way of implementing the XMLPullParserFactory to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a regex, for example `"\w*="([^"]*(?="))"`. This checks the following:

- `\w*` matches word-characters (like letters and numbers) until
- `=` the '=' is reached which simply matches the character '=',
- `[^"]*` first matches the^'"'-character (which represents the opening '"'-character) and then every character that is not '"' until
- `(?=")` is reached which checks if the next character is an '"'-character (which represents the closing '"'-character)

Use this regex like so: `myString.replace("\w*="([^"]*(?="))", "\1")`. That will replace the whole `Name="myName"` with simply `myName`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Yato for the insight on the matter. But I think I have found another way around the issue, I have used XMLPullParser to extract the specific substrings needed by me.

Comment: Yes, that may actually be more readable to others (or yourself in the future) than using a regex for this. Would you mind also writing this in an answer to your own question and accept it so other users will see what your solution for the problem was? :)